# Symfony2 - get or create route's arguments array?

Tags: php, symfony, session, routes

In the system (Symfony 2.8) for some objects we have "edit this" buttons both on object list and on the object's "details" page. My client suddenly wants all the forms to redirect to where he came from after submiting with correct data.
So I thought I could save origin in session and then redirect, but I'd like to do it in a bit generic way, like on every action which would allow to enter "edit" or "create" or anything, I would do:

```
$this->get('session')->set(
    'formOrigin', 
    [
        'route' => $this->get('request')->get('_route'),
        'arguments' => ???
    ]
)
```

And then after handling data from form, fetch origin from session and if not null

```
return $this->redirectToRoute($formOrigin['route'], $formOrigin['arguments']);
```

But the problem is that `???` in the code :) Can you give me a hint here?

To clarify, can I get route arguments as array "from somewhere", or do I have to build it by myself every time? I can build it, but it seems ugly to me...

Comment: could you use the [referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) as `$request->headers->get('referer')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you store `refrer` in session:

```
$referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
$this->get('session')->set('referer', $referer);
```

when entering the object edit and redirect to it after successfully form submission.

Or you can get `Route` params from `$request` object:

```
$routeParams = $request->attributes->get('_route_params');
```

Answer (score 0):

To do simple you can use listener :

Create a listener who listen your request and store the route in a session

for exmple in your bundleName/Resources/config/services.yml

```
services:
    redirect_listener:
        class: BundleName\EventListener\RedirectListener
        arguments: ['@service_container']
        tags:
            - {name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

BundleName/EventListener/RedirectListener.php

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class RedirectionListener
{
    protected $session;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $containerInterface)
    {
        $this->session = $containerInterface->get('session');
    }

    /**
     * @param GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $route = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route');

        if($this->session->has('route')) $this->session->remove('route');

        // Add route in session
        $this->session->add('route', $route);
    }



}
```

In you controller after handling data you can redirect

```
class YourController extends Controller
{

    public function yourHandleFormAction()
    {
        // After handling data
        $this->redirect($this->get('session')->get('route'));

    }
}
```